# Apache License: Why no recursion?

Tags: apache-license

So this is my question: supposedly we can use the Apache License to include externally-written modules of code, within our applications. Yet, if I'm not mistaken, the License seems to state that we are required to include a copy of the Apache License when we distribute our code.

Then, when the recipients of our application notice the Apache license, what's to prevent them from thinking that our application is also falling within the Apache License, and hence they would also have permission to modify and distribute our application?

Do we have to augment the Apache License to simply state that it only applies to a portion of our code, and provide a link to the original modules that were used/copied/implemented-from-an-outside-source?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> when the recipients of our application notice the Apache license, what's to prevent them from thinking that our application is also falling within the Apache License

Don't make them guess your license terms. You need to include your own license terms. And then have a paragraph about the modules you used and *their* respective license.

Answer (score 1):

> Then, when the recipients of our application notice the Apache license, what's to prevent them from thinking that our application is also falling within the Apache License, and hence they would also have permission to modify and distribute our application?

Nothing is to prevent them "thinking" that.

However, "thinking" that you / they are covered by a particular license is not good enough.  It won't satisfy a law court ... and it won't satisfy the person who is providing legal advice to the user of your application.

**Everyone** is best served if you are crystal clear what licensing terms apply to your application.  And the fact that the Apache license requires you to do this merely means that you can't choose to be vague about it.

Furthermore, if you fail to comply with the terms of a "copyright based license", then you are violating the copyright of the software you are using, and that places *you* at legal risk.

Just do it.